# Reading a substring with spaces from a line in C

Tags: c, substring, scanf

I have an ASCII file with header information.  One of the lines in the header is like this:

`# John Q. Public et al. 2014, to be submitted`

I am trying to get the name.  Here is my code:

`sscanf(line,"# %s et al.",NAME);`

Unfortunately, it only gets the first name.  Note:  the name can be 1 or more tokens separated by blanks.  Basically, I need to get everything between the first hash mark, and the "et al." into a single string (char*) variable.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: read the line with `fgets()` then parse it.

Comment: fgets is better way but another is `scanf("%[^\n]", s)` to read till  you press enter

Comment: OK ... do all authors have "et al."? Is there always a year after "et al." followed by a comma? ... ... ...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need something native:

```
bool readName(const char *line, char *name, int bufferSize)
{
    const char *hash = strstr(line, "# ");
    if(!hash)
        return false;
    const char *etal = strstr(hash+2, " et al.");
    if(!etal)
        return false;
    size_t numChars = min(etal-hash-2, bufferSize-1);
    strncpy(name, hash+2, numChars);
    name[numChars] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(name, hash+2, min(etal-hash-2, bufferSize-1));` does not `'\0'` terminate `name`.

Comment: Thanks chux, I corrected this. I know this topic is old but I don't like wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the line into memory as @pgm suggests then use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to extract the name. I can't give a specific example without knowing the platform/libraries you are using.

Comment: The line has already been read from a file with `fgets()`.  Now that I have the line, I am trying to get the name out of it.  But I can only get the first token of the whole name.  I am working on Linux using gnu compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void between(const char *str, const char *key1, const char *key2, char *out){
    char *from, *to, *p;
    *out = '\0';
    from = strstr(str, key1);
    if(!from) return ;
    from += strlen(key1);
    to = strstr(from, key2);
    if(!to) return ;//or rest ?
    while(isspace(*from))
        ++from;
    while(isspace(*--to))
        ;
    for(p = from; p <= to; )
        *out++ = *p++;
    *out = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char line[] = "# John Q. Public et al. 2014, to be submitted";
    char NAME[32];
    between(line, "#", "et al.", NAME);
    printf("<%s>\n", NAME);//<John Q. Public>

    return 0;
}
```